# Getting all resname in each Restaurant0, 1 , 2 ,3 and so on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

My code is working but it only gets the first resname in Restaurant0

```js
public class caloocan  extends AppCompatActivity {
    String FIREBASE_URL = "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/Restaurant0/resname";
  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

        firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String restName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
               final String[] res = {restName};

                for (int x = 1; x==5 ; x++) {
                    String xString = String.valueOf(x);
                    String FIREBASE_URLCOUNTER = "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/Restaurant" + xString;
                    String FIREBASE_URL = " https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/Restaurant" + xString + "/resname/";
                   firebaseCounter = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URLCOUNTER);
                    res [x] = restName;
                }
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(caloocan.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, res);
                restauList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRest);
                restauList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

here is the database[image]

is something wrong with the looping statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and tell me if it works,

```
String FIREBASE_URL = "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String[] res = new String[dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()]; 
            int i=0;
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                   res[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resname").getValue().toString();
                   i++;
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(caloocan.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, res);
            restauList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRest);
            restauList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
   }
 }
```

Comment: solved! i casted your edited answer into

 String[] res = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];

thanks! cheers!

Comment: Mark it as the selected answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing only the values at `Restaurant0` by pointing your url to it.

```
String FIREBASE_URL = "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/Restaurant0/resname";
```

According to screenshot it should be like

```
String FIREBASE_URL = "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/restaulist1";
```

Comment: i have 

String FIREBASE_URL = " https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/Restaurant" + xString + "/resname/";

on the looping statement to switch to another url . should i create new ValueEventListener inside the loop ?

Comment: first Log the output of `dataSnapshot.getValue` and check what it logs and update in your question. Then it will be easy to understand how to parse

Comment: it logs the the restname of Restaurant0 . is there sometthing i need to change in my code in `dataSnapshop.getValue` inside the loop

Comment: you have not changed the url yet right ? .. if you change the url to the one i specified in my answer, you will get different output in log.

Comment: inside of `ValueEventListener` there's a loop that change the URL of the destined database . i think the problem in my code is inside the `for`

Comment: you actually dont need to change url if you access the root most object, that is why i have asked you to change url so that we can solve it easily.

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference` 
error dataSnapshop can't get items from "https://restaulist1.firebaseio.com/restaulist1";

Comment: can you attach a full image to your db, it seems to be cut off from the top.